# Update image on button click

Tags: python, flet

Can someone explain to me how do I update a property of an element from a function called from another element, like in the example below?
In this example, I created a flet app which shows 4 elements. The two elements at the top are images and the ones at the bottom are buttons. Now, I'd like to click the buttons and change the images. How do I do that? I already tried to change it through the controls, but I was not able to do it.

```
import numpy as np
import base64
import flet
from flet import Image, Page, Row, TextButton
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image as image

arr = np.zeros((400, 400, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
pil_img = image.fromarray(arr)
buff = BytesIO()
pil_img.save(buff, format="JPEG")
image_string = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")

def main(page: Page):
    page.title = "My Page"
    page.theme_mode = "light"
    page.padding = 50

    page.update()

    def update_load_button(value):
        img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (400, 400, 3), np.uint8)
        pil_img = image.fromarray(img)
        buff = BytesIO()
        pil_img.save(buff, format="JPEG")
        new_image_string = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
        ## CHANGE IMAGE HERE ##
        page.update()

    def update_predict_button(v):
        pass

    page.add(
        Row(controls=[
            Image(src_base64=image_string),
            Image(src_base64=image_string)
        ], alignment='center'),
        Row(controls=[
            TextButton("Load_image", on_click=update_load_button),
            TextButton("Predict", on_click=update_predict_button)
        ], alignment='center')
    )
    page.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the value only of the Image.

Click on Load image to change the 2. image's color:

```
import numpy as np
import base64
import flet
from flet import Image, Page, Row, TextButton
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image as image

arr = np.zeros((400, 400, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
pil_img = image.fromarray(arr)
buff = BytesIO()
pil_img.save(buff, format="JPEG")

def main(page: Page):
    image_string = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
    page.title = "My Page"
    page.theme_mode = "light"
    page.padding = 50
    img_1 = Image(src_base64=image_string)
    img_2 = Image(src_base64=image_string)

    # page.update()   # not needed!

    def update_load_button(value):
        img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (400, 400, 3), np.uint8)
        pil_img = image.fromarray(img)
        buff = BytesIO()
        pil_img.save(buff, format="JPEG")
        
        new_image_string = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
        img_2.src_base64 = new_image_string  # img_2's value updated
        ## CHANGE IMAGE HERE ##
        img_2.update()  # only img_2 widget will be updated

    def update_predict_button(v):
        pass

    page.add(
        Row(controls=[
            img_1,
            img_2
        ], alignment='center'),
        Row(controls=[
            TextButton("Load_image", on_click=update_load_button),
            TextButton("Predict", on_click=update_predict_button)
        ], alignment='center')
    )
    # page.update() # not needed, every widget can be stateless (only Image not)
    
flet.app(target=main)
```

Comment: Excellent solution!
The only one that worked for me!!