# How to update an image frame displayed in Flet

Tags: python, flet

I'm working with some recognition prompt which runs beside my actual program, these recog prompt cut and resize an image, constantly saving/deleting the image, changing it by the most actual recog frame.

Now, my problem is how to implement it with Flet, I've actually tried some common ways, which use `ft.Image()` and `page.update()`, container update and even controls update. But the image stays the same even if I erase it from my computer and the other image has the same name and format in the folder.

Here's an example of what I've tried.

```
import time
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):

    i = ft.Image(src='Python\\plate_0.jpg', on_animation_end= page.update())

    def animate(e):
        sw.content = ft.Image(
            src=f'Python\\plate_0.jpg{time.time()}'
        )
        page.update()

    sw = ft.AnimatedSwitcher(
        i,
        transition=ft.AnimatedSwitcherTransition.SCALE,
        duration=500,
        reverse_duration=500,
        switch_in_curve=ft.AnimationCurve.BOUNCE_OUT,
        switch_out_curve=ft.AnimationCurve.BOUNCE_IN,
    )

    page.add(
        sw,
        ft.ElevatedButton("Animate!", on_click=animate),
    )

ft.app(target=main)
```

This code displays the image, but when it is replaced on the OS, even if you click on "Animate" nothing happens beside the screen going blank. I've made other tests, creating a class (`ImageSwitcher`), using OpenCV to read the image and even abusing the `page.update()` on every possible way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update image on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73527782/update-image-on-button-click)

Comment: I guess this was the closest that I can reach, at this moment I can display the image with the provided code, but even if i change the "randint" properly by my image path, nothing happens. I'll keep trying, if I have any progress, I'll be back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I found the solution, and it's quite simple if you think properly. If the file name stays the same, but the older image is gone, then you'll need to declare a "new-same" file path, so the code will search the file again.

```
import numpy as np
import base64
import flet as ft
from flet import Image
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image as image

image_path = r"Python\\plate_0.jpg" # First Reachable Path
pil_photo = image.open(image_path) # Pillow Opens the Image
arr = np.asarray(pil_photo) # Numpy transforms it into an array

pil_img = image.fromarray(arr) # Then you convert it in an image again
buff = BytesIO() # Buffer
pil_img.save(buff, format="JPEG") # Save it

def main(page= ft.Page):
    image_string = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
    image1 = Image(src_base64=image_string)
    page.window_width = 375
    page.window_height = 300

    def updateTest(value):
        image_path = r"Python\\plate_0.jpg" # Read the path again

        pil_photo = image.open(image_path)

        arr = np.asarray(pil_photo)
        pil_img = image.fromarray(arr)
        buff = BytesIO()
        pil_img.save(buff, format="JPEG")

        newstring = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
        image1.src_base64 = newstring

        image1.update() # "Voí'la"

    page.add(
        ft.Row(controls=[
            image1
        ], alignment='center'),
        ft.Row(controls=[
            ft.TextButton("Test", on_click=updateTest)
        ], alignment='center')
    )

ft.app(target=main)
```